# why my java program did't work properly for creating a triangle pattern?

Tags: java

```
package prac1;

public class pattern1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i=0; i<4 ;i++) {
            //block of code
            for(int j=0; j<3-i; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            for(int k=0; k<i+k; k++) {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
            for(int j=0; j<3-i; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
/**
---1---
--111--
-11111-
1111111
*/
```

Comment: Please make sure everything is formatted correctly before posting.

Comment: you need to explain what you want to achieve and what doesn't work

Comment: i can't create a triangle pattern by the program

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Clearly describe actual vs expected output.

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question with description of *specific* problem you are having. "Program doesn't work properly" is not *specific* problem description, it can be used to almost all questions here. Describe what your code is *supposed* to do and what it does *instead*.

Comment: There's an infinite loop for starters: As soon as `k<i+k` is `true`, it will always be true as k increases. Ex: `1<1+1` --> `2<1+2` --> `3<1+3` etc. Change it to `k<i` and it already looks a lot closer to what you want it to look like

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working properly because of below infinite loop, In below loop `k<i+k` is never terminating condition.

```
 for(int k=0; k<i+k; k++) 
  {
      System.out.print("1");
  }
```

You can change it to

```
for(int k=0; k<=2*i; k++)
   {
     System.out.print("1");
   }
```

Here is correct code

```
public static void main(String []args){
        for(int i=0; i<4 ;i++) {
            //block of code
            for(int j=0; j<3-i; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }
            for(int k=0; k<=2*i; k++) {
                System.out.print("1");
            }
            for(int j=0; j<3-i; j++) {
                System.out.print("-");
            }

            System.out.print("\n");
        }
     }
```